# How can one get the value of the point where the AxMapControl is centered at?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects, c#

I am using the AxMapControl to display a map and I want to record a point where I am and want to be able to return to the same point later on using the CenterAt() method.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  Would you be able to edit your Question to provide a few more details (code snippets) to show what you have tried and where you are stuck, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AxMapcontrol has a property *Extent* which returns an [envelope](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/IEnvelope_Interface/002m00000169000000/), from this the average X and average Y would be the centre:

```
double CentX = ( MapControl.Extent.Xmin + MapControl.Extent.Xmax ) / 2;
double CentY = ( MapControl.Extent.Ymin + MapControl.Extent.Ymax ) / 2;

IPoint CentPoint = new PointClass();
IPoint.PutCoords(CentX,CentY);
IPoint.SpatialReference = MapControl.SpatialReference;
```

You can `CenterAt()` this [IPoint](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/IPoint_Interface/002m0000026v000000/) later, the spatial reference is the same as the map so you should have no problems.. you could consider keeping the extent object if you want the map to zoom to exactly the same spot with the same scale.